# Game server for an android/iOS turn-based board-game

Tags: android, iphone, multiplayer

i'm currently programming an iPhone game and I would like to create an online multiplayer mode. In the future, this app will be port to Android devices, so I was wondering how to create the game-server ?

First at all, which language should I choose ? How to make a server able to communicate both with programs written in objective-c and Java ?

Then, how to effectively do it ? Is it good if I open a socket by client (there'll be 2) ? What kind of information should I send to the server ? to the clients ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: how massively multiplayer'ed will it be?

Comment: I don't really know, but i don't expect billion players, but maybe some thousands...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT** How massively multiplayer'ed will you game be?

Hi Cyril,

as you noticed, there are two main things two consider:

1. information sent to the server
2. information sent to the client

There's only *one* type of information to sent to the server: the user inputs.  If you don't do that, you'll encounter headaches over headaches when rogue client will try to send fake data to your server (like saying *"My tank now has 100 000 000 armor"*).

Then what you sent to the client is up to you but it's totally possible to only sent to the client the other player(s)'s input.  This is the way to have the absolute minimum and tinies bandwith usage possible.  That is how games like Blizzard's *Warcraft 3* are doing it.  As a bonus, this makes for tiny replay files (because all you need to do to be able to replay a game is the time (and the input) at which each player's input happened).

The one downsides with sending only the other player's input to the client is that it means all the game's logic is present on every client.  For some games, this may be an issue because people may cheat by reverse engineering your game and finding flaws.  This issue can be mitigated with careful, controlled, randomization (where in addition to the input+time you send input+time+*randomness* where *randomness* cannot be guessed by the client in advance.

Another way to do it is to do some logic computation on the server side.  Then, obviously, you need to send the result of the server computation to the client.  Done correctly, this has the benefit of both preventing cheats *and* maky piracy impossible (for example **nobody** managed to play World of Warcraft in the real economy --that is, on the real Blizzard servers-- using a fake licence key).

Regarding the phone-turn-based game server: just look at one top-selling turn-based game are doing it.  Take Uniwar for example: works on iPhone and Android.  Game server is written in Java "of course".

The one thing to realize is that a game like the one you plan to write is entirely deterministic: if you can't easily code a replayer or if you can't easily reproduce any kind of scenario leading to a logic bug, you're doing it wrong.

Note that being determistic doesn't mean you can't add what looks like randomness to your players: it's simply that the randomness shall also be deterministic (for example by simply using a different seed for each game + the time at which player inputs are made as a fake random source).

Comment: Hi and thanks. This is really interesting bug i've still a question in mind : how to serialize data. I mean, assuming that my server know the 8*8 array that represents the game-board, how to send the game state to the client ? Then how the client can serialize a move from a cell (eg. Player 1 from [0,0] to [1,1]) ?

Comment: @Cyril: first you can go even further than that.  By serializing players input, I really mean inputs, at their lowest level: *at time t  player hit the key 3*.  Then your server shall find itself that it means *"Player 1 from [0,0] to [1,1]"* because your server knows that player 1 is at [0,0] (your server knows everything) and your server knows the player's mapping for key 3 means "go down and right".  You have to realize that otherwise people could cheat by sending *"Player 1 from [0,0] to [42,42]"* even though moving by 42 units in one move would be provided.  Send the inputs, really.

Comment: @Cyril: By "input" I mean input as in "I/O".  User inputs.  Key pressed, screen touched, mouse moved, etc.  The closest to actual physical input you can get.   Now, regarding the actual transmission of data: I know some turn-based games simply go for HTTP GET/POST because this is quite easy to set up.

Comment: @Cyril: **WAIT**... You wrote *"how to send the game state to the client?"* but... You precisely do **NEVER** send the game state. You send inputs.  Inputs allow to recreated the exact same game state on every client.  That is what I explained in my answer.

Comment: Note that going the synchronised state / deterministic route in your game model you may run into floating point errors between platforms causing desynchronisations

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit lateral solution to the question asked. One of your options is to use Gamooga (http://www.gamooga.com/) so you donot need to worry about the server side, the sockets, the transport logic etc. You can just concentrate on your game logic and just develop that than the required systems stuff.

Gamooga provides you with a realtime communication platform to be used in your games. You can upload your server side message processing scripts to Gamooga's cluster and use its iOS API with in your app to send and receive messages from/to the server side. The server side is auto scaled and managed for you by Gamooga. You can download the SDK and start off with the demos with in the SDK.

Disclosure: I am founder of Gamooga, replying only since its relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have two thoughts for you in mind:

---

## Message Serialization

Most programming languages are capable of this by default or using a standard library.
if you are not sure what to do, use JSON and fail fast   ;-)

---

## Game Server

A game with slow/asynchonous interactions may be suitable for the 'Proof-Of-Turn' algorithm given in this **open source** thesis paper:

- Original: https://arxiv.org/abs/2304.07384
- Alternative link: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/370070433

The thesis covers the following problems:

- Servercosts, which can be eliminated using rotating (mobile) hosts.
- Trust among players, as the state is open to everyone.
- Distributed consent in regards of 'fair randomness'.
- Problems which stem from rotating hosts.
- Games which use likewise structures.
- List of game mechanics, which benefit/prohibit the use of rotating hosts.

As the thesis takes multiple perspectives on the topic in over 80 pages, you better take a look for yourself.

In chapter `4.8 Further Characteristics`, bulletpoint **4)** all needed settings for a "Reference Implementation" are given.

Maybe you can gains benefit from this   :)

**Disclosure:**

- I wrote the `master thesis`/`paper`, replying only since its relevant to the question.

Best wishes   ;-)